# jQuery/PHP Select checkboxes from $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, jquery

I'm not sure if I'm doing this completely wrong, but I'm hoping what I'm trying to do is possible.

I have an existing ajax jquery function that saves the "selected" checkboxes from a user and stores them in $_SESSION['order_items'][index]['cheeseids'][]; When a user goes to recall this "item", I'd like to have the same checkboxes "selected" as before. See example below:

```
[order_items] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [cheeseids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [2] => 4
                    )
```

My "change/restore" jquery function uses the following variables to get the index number:

```
var productIDValSplitter   = (this.id).split("_");
var productIDVal       = productIDValSplitter[1];
```

The function I'm trying to use to "re-select" boxes 1, 2, 4 (from cheeseids array) is not working (it is inside my jQuery function). It actually causes the entire jQuery code to not work:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['order_items'] as $key => $value)
{
?>

var idnum = <?php echo $value['<script type="text/javascript">productIDVal</script>']['cheeseids']  ?>;
$("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]").eq(" + idnum + ").attr("checked", "checked");

<?php
}
?>
```

JS Output:

```
var idnum = ;
$("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]").eq(" + idnum + ").attr("checked", "checked");

var idnum = ;
$("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]").eq(" + idnum + ").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Entire JS/jQuery function that I'm adding the PHP too:

```
$("#basketItemsWrap li img.change").live("click", function(event) {
        var productIDValSplitter   = (this.id).split("_");
        var productIDVal       = productIDValSplitter[1];  
        $("#notificationsLoader").show();
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "includes/ajax/functions.php",
        data: { productID: productIDVal, action: "deleteFromBasket"},  
        success: function(theResponse) {
          $("div#order_qty input").attr('value', $("#order_" + productIDVal + " #order_qty").text());
          $("div#order_listprice input#price1").attr('value', $("#order_" + productIDVal + " #order_listprice").text().replace("$", ""));
          $("div#order_price input#discprice1").attr('value', $("#order_" + productIDVal + " #order_price").text().replace("$", ""));
          $("div#order_price input#itemprice1").attr('value', $("#order_" + productIDVal + " #order_itemprice").text().replace("$", ""));


          //The following functions restore the order details in the select menus, checkboxes, and radio buttons
          //Restores the item selected
          for(var i = 0; i < $("#item1 option").size(); i++)
          {
            if($("#order_" + productIDVal + " #order_item").text() == $("#item1 option:eq("+i+")").text())
            {
              $("#item1 option:eq("+i+")").attr("selected", "selected");
              //$("#item1").val(i);
              CalcPrice(1);
            }
          }

          //Restores the promotion selected
          for(var i = 0; i < $("#promo1 option").size(); i++)
          {
            if($("#order_" + productIDVal + " #order_promo").text() == $("#promo1 option:eq("+i+")").text())
            {
              $("#promo1 option:eq("+i+")").attr("selected", "selected");
              //$("#promo1").val(i);
              CalcPromo(1);
            }
          }

            <?php foreach($_SESSION['order_items'][1]['cheeseids'] as $id): ?>
             $("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]#<?php echo $id;?>").attr("checked", "checked");
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          //Restores the cheese options selected



          // $('div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]').size(); i++)

          //$('div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]').eq(1).attr('checked', 'checked');


          $("#order_" + productIDVal).hide("slow",  function() {$(this).remove();Calc();});
          $("#notificationsLoader").hide();
        }  
        }); 
      });
```

PHP/HTML code to generate the checkboxes:

```
<?php
        //Display all "cheese" options in a checkbox group
          foreach($_SESSION['ingr_cheese'] as $key => $value)
          {
              echo "<div class=\"cheesebox\" style=\"float:left; width:175px; margin-bottom:7px;\">";
              echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cheese1\" id=\"cheese1\" class=\"cheeseCheck\" value=\"".$key."\">&nbsp;<label for=\"cheese1\">".$value['cheese']."</label></br>";
              echo "</div>";
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error. Can you include the js that is output from the `foreach` in your last code block?

Comment: Just posted it to the original. It is a syntax error. I don't know how to properly format the jq and the php to work together.

Comment: Thanks, and sure enough, that's some invalid javascript. I'll take a swing at an answer now..

Answer (score 0):

If the array you listed is already is an accurate representation of what's in the `$_SESSION` array, then this code should do what you're looking for.

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['order_items'][1]['cheeseids'] as $id): ?>
    $("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]#<?php echo $id;?>").attr("checked", "checked");
<?php endfor; ?>
```

This should generate javascript that looks like this:

```
    $("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]#1").attr("checked", "checked");
    $("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]#2").attr("checked", "checked");
    $("div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]#4").attr("checked", "checked");
```

This code assumes your markup for the checkboxes looks (somewhat) like this:

```
<div class=".cheesebox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="4">
</div>
```

I verified the selector syntax, but if that doesn't work, then I probably made a bad assumption about the markup of your checkboxes. Paste in some more of your html if this isn't enough to point you in the right direction and I'll take another swing at it.

Comment: When I put that php code inside my jQuery function it no longer works. Do I need to separate out the php from the js? I will add the entire function to my original post in a second.

Comment: Also, how do I specific the $_SESSION['order_items'][1]['cheeseids'] index value of "1" as a javascript var (productIDval? example: $_SESSION['order_items][productIDVal]['cheeseids']?

Comment: I'm wondering if this won't actually work....because the js call to change the foreach loop will be after the server call. Maybe I need to save each "cheeseid" value in a javascript array and loop through that array? The other functions that recall the drop-down menus in the same function do this. However, I'm not sure how to loop through the js array like a php "foreach" loop.